# Lollipop Contact Count

Tags: contacts, 5.0-lollipop

I have a Nexus 6 with Lollipop 5.0. I am wondering how many contacts I have on my phone. Of course I could go through and count each one but is there a way to put the contact count at the bottom sort of like the iPhone contact count. How

How can I enable this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In the *Contacts* app, press the *Menu* button and select `Memory status`.
Then you get a screen displaying you the total number of contacts used for every single account/storage.
This only works for custom ROMs, though (don't know why).

[image]

Comment: When I press the menu button, I don't see a Memory status. I see setting. Under settings there is only sorting.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I see `Displayed contacts`, `Import/Export`, `Accounts`, `Settings`, `Delete` and `Memory status`. Also I am on Lollipop, too. So that's strange.

Comment: Wait. I don't have developer mode on. Do you?

Comment: I have it on by default, but that's not the issue. Developer mode does not interfere with any apps (not even changing the menu).

Comment: I tried it with Dev mode on and it didn't work. Huh. That's strange

Comment: is it possible that it was removed in the update? I believe I have android 5.0.1.

Comment: I have 5.0.2 (CM12) and I see Memory status. @GiantTree, are you running Google android or CM (or some fork of CM)?

Comment: I am using a CM fork (Resurrection Remix) with Android 5.0.2.

Comment: FYI, this feature is not available on stock Android. Please include a note mentioning the custom ROM on the answer.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. I'll add that ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it on the phone at all. Log into your gmail account on the desktop, switch to the contacts tab, and the number is displayed after "My Contacts"

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an app that counts your contacts. It is called [Contact Counter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mkit.contactcounter) and eagerly waiting for users ;o)

Comment: You might consider adding a link to the app on the Play Store (or Github or wherever it's available from).

Answer (score -2):

Just scroll down to the bottom of the Contact list -- you'll find the total # of contacts

Comment: Can you add more details please. Maybe it is specific to your phone /OS. I haven't seen that anywhere